# django+ ajax отправка формы

Tags: ajax, django

есть форма, в которой 2 поля имя и email
во views.py

```
def get_name(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_code = generate_code(8)
    subject = 'код подтверждения' 
    message = user_code
    mail = request.POST['mail']
    form = NameForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        Registration.objects.create(fio=request.POST['fio'],mail=request.POST['mail'],code=user_code)
        send_mail(subject, message,settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,[mail],fail_silently=False)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('endreg')
else:
    form = NameForm()
return render(request, 'registers/detail.html', {'form': form})
```

смысл в том что на почту приходит код подтверждения который потом надо ввести в другую форму

```
def endreg(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NameForm1(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        code_use = form.cleaned_data.get("key")
        try:
            user = Registration.objects.get(code=code_use)
            user.verification = True
            user.save() 
            messages.warning(request, u'Спасибо за регистрацию.')
        except:
            messages.warning(request, u'Не правильны код!Введите код с почты.')
else:
    form = NameForm1()
return render(request, 'registers/endreg.html', {'form': form})
```

сама форма в html

```
<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off" id="my_form">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="contact-form" >
   <h1>{%trans 'Регистрация' %}</h1>
   <div class="txtb">{{form.fio.label}} {{form.fio}}{{form.fio.help_text}}</div>
   <div class="txtb1"> {{form.phone.label}}{{form.phone}}</div>  
   <input type="submit" value="{%trans 'Отправить' %}" class="btn" id="btn">   
  </div>
</form>
```

в общем вопрос как сделать так, чтобы 2 форма появлялась на этой же страницы, без обновления? 
Буду благодарен если поможете разобраться 
я так понимаю форму нужно отправлять через ajax .
Можно ли вообще такое реализовать и как?
А то меня смущает факт того что на страницу endreg можно зайти до страницы detail
написал такой ajax запрос

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#btn").submit(function(event){ 
        $.ajax({ 
            type:"POST", 
            url:"127.0.0.1:8000", 
            data: { 
                'fio': $('#id_fio').val(), 
                'email': $('#id_email').val(), 
            }, 
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                 document.getElementById("my_form").replaceWith(data.form1);
            }
        });
        }); 
    });
```

и во views.py заменил HttpRessponeRedirect на `return JsonResponse({'name_form1': render_to_string('registers/endreg.html')})`
в итоге на странице появляется текст сhtml формой а не форма, как поправить
[image: вот что выводит после return JsonResponse({'name_form1': render_to_string('registers/endreg.html')})]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вам нужно отправить форму на `get_name` с помощью ajax. После этого вам стоит заменить строку `HttpResponseRedirect` на `JsonResponse` который будет содержать dict с вашей версткой формы. Что то вроде этого `JsonResponse({'name_form1': 'html код формы'})`. Так как верстка вашей формы строится шаблоном django, вы вероятно захотите отрендерить ее в строку. Для этого django предоставляет специальную функцию `render_to_string('путь/к/шаблону/второй/формы.html')`. Соответственно у вас должно получится что то вроде этого:`return JsonResponse({'name_form1': render_to_string('путь/к/шаблону/второй/формы.html')})`.
2. На стороне клиента при помощи js вы должны вставить html в нужное вам место. Вторую форму так же отправлять через ajax только уже на другой url (на тот на котором у вас висит обработчик `endreg`) для этого в верстке второй формы должно быть `<form action="/url/на/который/отправляем" method="post">`.
3. В `endreg` вам нужно разрешить только метод POST. что бы на страницу нельзя было перейти из браузера. И при неверном коде, ошибку так же придется возвращать при помощи `JsonResponse({'error': 'Не правильны код!Введите код с почты.'})` как и успех `JsonResponse({'message': 'Спасибо за регистрацию.'})`. И выводить в эти сообщения в нужных местах. Либо как вариант можно при успехе делать перенаправление на другую страницу, на которой будет написано успех.
4. Ссылки:
   [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects),
   [render_to_string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#usage) (сделайте поиск по странице)

Надеюсь смог чем то помочь.

Comment: вроде как я вас понял. и уже что-то попытался реализовать, и даже это что-то похоже что работает)
вот вопрос по 2 пункту.
после return JsonResponse({'name_form1': render_to_string('путь/к/шаблону/второй/формы.html')})
после отправки формы мне возвращает верстку страницы со 2 формой
не совсем понял что с ней делать

Comment: Вам нужна не верстка страницы, а верстка формы. Вынесите вёрстку формы в отдельный файл. И потом с помощью js вам эту вёрстку просто нужно будет вставить в нужное место на странице. Например можно заменить предыдущую первую форму на вторую.

Comment: я подправил вопрос, скинул что сделал и что получил
не как вставить верстку через js? 
в js не очень силен к сожалению(

Comment: `document.getElementById("my_form").replaceWith(result.name_form1);`
Этот код заменит старую форму, на  ту что вам пришла.
В переменную result запишите то что вывели в консоль.

Comment: я так понимаю мне это все надо писать в ajax запросе
добавить что-то вроде success: function(data) {
        document.getElementById("my_form").replaceWith(result.name_form1);
    } 
?
что-то я совсем запутался что мне делать надо

Comment: Да, только у вас переменная `data` а у меня называется `result` поэтому нужно название поменять  `document.getElementById("my_form").replaceWith(data.name_form1);`. Примерно так.

Comment: я так пробовал, в браузере отображается все равно тоже самое что и в прикрепленном скрине к вопросу

Comment: можете загрузить весь код на github и дать ссылку? что бы я смог воспроизвести все у себя.

Comment: Ваша проблема была в следующем
1. вы вешали событие submit на кнопку, а не на форму
2. так как по умолчанию событие submit перезагружает страницу, то нужно предотвратить это поведение.

`$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#my_form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: $this.serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $this.html(data.form1);
      },
      error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });
});`

Comment: Вот так должен выглядеть код js. Но форму вы не увидите так как вы не передали ее при рендере. Вам нужно во view.py в функции get_name сделать следующее `return JsonResponse({
                'form1': render_to_string(
                    'registers/endreg.html', {'form': NameForm1(), }
                )
            })`

Comment: Так же в дальнейшем там будут еще проблемы. Вам следует получше ознакомится с django, а так же с использование ajax в js. Потому что ваш вопрос очень глобальный и охватывает очень много всяких нюансов.

Comment: это помогло спасибо, только не совсем понял как передаются все данные